# An Introductory Book on Newton Polygons

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-number-theory, book-recommendation

Could anyone recommend a book (or any online material) for a beginner that gives an introduction to [Newton polygons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton_polygon) containing some worked out examples and discusses the motivation behind such polygons.

Comment: Besides what others have posted, see the references posted at mathoverflow at [Newton and Newton polygon](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/15703/newton-and-newton-polygon).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want Gouvêa’s book “$p$-adic Numbers”, where section 6.4 seems to have an excellent treatment.

Comment: Dear @Lubin, Thank you very much.

Comment: Dear @Lubin, Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Not a book, but a PDF file containing the transcript of a [talk on Newton polygons](http://people.math.sc.edu/filaseta/gradcourses/Math788F/NewtonPolygonsTalk.pdf).